# Sails.js: Creating multiple records dependant of the previous ones

Tags: asynchronous, sails.js, waterline

I have a model called `Task`. It has an attribute called `dependencies`, which stores information (array of task IDs) about which tasks should be completed before one can continue to process the task.

Now, I have a situation where I have an array of objects. I'm creating `Task`s based on the attributes of each of these objects. The catch is that each of the created tasks is dependant on the previous created task, but Waterline's asynchronicity gets in the way here since I can't just loop through every object and save the dependency ID in a variable after creating each record.

In synchronous pseudocode, here's what I'd like to happen:

```
var dep = undefined, t = undefined;
var objects = [object1, object2, object3, object4] // array of objects
for object in objects {
    object.dependancy = dep;
    t = createTaskBasedOnObject(object); // assuming this'd return the created object
    dep = t.id; // Change dep so the next object has the created task as a dependency
};
```

What would be the best way to do this? I'm fine with using external libraries if required or if it makes things any easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) library to do that. It's globally exposed in a Sails project.

```
async.each(objects, function (object, next) {
  object.dependancy = dep;
  createTaskBasedOnObject(object, function (e, t) {
    // handle errors...

    dep = t.id;
    return next();
  });
});
```